# how to get a specific output from different elements of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to get a specific output for an element which doesn't belong in a list, I wish to perform the following function:
I have defined a `list(lst1)` ,the program then asks for an input from the user and then converts the given integer to a list and compares the input to `lst1`. If the elements don't match correctly (even 1)
then the program prints that the specific element doesn't belong in the given list (example showed below):

```
lst1=[1,2,3]

a=int(input())

b=a.split()
```

now for eg i enter 234

i wish to get an output:

```
'4' does not belong in lst1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
lst1=[1,2,3]
a=int(input())

user_input = [int(i) for i in str(a)]

for num in user_input: 
    if num not in lst1:
        raise ValueError(f"{num} does not belong to lst1")
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `set` difference:

```
lst1=[1,2,3]
a=int(input())

user_input = [int(i) for i in str(a)]

if len(set(user_input) - set(lst1)) > 0:
    raise ValueError("...")
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to handle multiple user inputs the following will do the trick:

```
lst1=[1,2,3]
a = input().split(' ')

user_input = [int(i) for i in a]

for _input in user_input:
    for num in [int(i) for i in str(_input)]:
        if num not in lst1:
            print(f"{num} does not belong to lst1")
```

or

```
lst1=[1,2,3]
a = input().split(' ')

user_input = [int(i) for i in a]

for _input in user_input:
    num = [int(i) for i in str(_input)]

    diff = set(num) - set(lst1)
    if len(diff) > 0:
        print(f"The following numbers are invalid: {diff}")
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering! this worked when i had only 1 number(like 2 or 24) i was wondering if there was a way to compare more than one numbers like for example ,taking lst1=[1,2,3]  and input as 2  3 , then the program returning the appropriate output.

Comment: like a =int(input())  # the input is 2 3

Comment: @AaryanshSahay I've edited my answer so you can handle multiple user inputs. Hope it helps.

Comment: hey i have another doubt, when i input lets sat 2 4 5 , it only shows the value error on 4 and not on 5 , how can we correct this? id like both 4 and 5 show a valueerror,thanks a lot!

Comment: @AaryanshSahay Edited my answer. You can now see all invalid numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> a=set([int(x) for x in raw_input()])
234
>>> [x for x in a if x not in lst1]
[4]
>>>
```

You can also make `lst1` a set (`set(lst1)`) for faster access and do something like `a - lst1` as well (which results in `set([4])`).

**EDIT**:

```
>>> lst1 = set(lst1)
>>> for i in a - lst1:
    print (str(i) + ' does not belong to lst1')


4 does not belong to lst1
>>>
```